# Move files from all directories to parent directory using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following file structure:

```
- Parent
  - folder1
     - file1
  - folder2
     - file2
  - folder3
     - file3
```

And i want the file1, file2, file3 to be moved to parent directory.
The problem is to find out all directories inside the parent directory.I am trying to implement something like this:

```
- name: Moving file.
  command: mv /parent/{{item}}/* /parent
  with_items: "folders in parent"
```

Any approach will be fine for me. I don't have any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [with_fileglob](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#id4).

```
- name: Moving file.
  command: mv {{ item }} /parent/
  with_fileglob:
    - /parent/*/*
```

Comment: thanks a lot @udondan. It worked. And how can i delete those empty folders ??

Comment: I personally do not like shell/command tasks and would rather create a new python module to do the whole job. Though a quick solution would be to run something like this: `- command: find /parent -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;`